# Creating a password-protected task in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, administrator, hibernate, scheduled-tasks

I would like to configure a task like "child control software",
so it would hibernate the pc at certain times.

Is it possible to prevent modification (here: pausing) of 
a task through requiring the entering of the admin password to modify,
EVEN THOUGH the currently-logged-in (and only) user is
the admin account itself?

(Do you know of any child control software that does NOT require
an additional account yet is able to hibernate the system at
certain times?)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's wrong with an additional account?

Comment: Agreed with ceejayoz. Win7 also has some nice child control features built in that are ridiculously easy to set: lockout times per account, software restrictions by rating/content (assuming they've been ESRB rated, which all consumer games are) are the two that spring to mind.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. Just make a separate account for your kid. Windows 7 makes it dead easy. You really shouldn't be letting your kid use an administrator account anyways -- too much potential for them to wreak accidental havoc on the system. Plus, if they have admin access, they can essentially find a way to whatever they want, including disable whatever you might be able to implement.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, I think you're approaching this the wrong way. But, I'll answer anyways.

The task scheduler is an MMC (Microsoft Management Console) snap-in. It therefore requires UAC elevation to run. With Windows 7's default UAC configuration, you won't actually get a prompt for it, because it's a system configuration action. The regular GUI configuration options for UAC don't let you do this, but you can configure UAC to require that you enter the account's password instead of just clicking "OK", and that it prompt for all actions.

If you have Win7 Pro or Ultimate, you can do this from the security policy editor. Run `secpol.msc`, and navigate to `Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options`. Find the setting `User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode`. Set it to `Prompt for credentials on the secure desktop`.

[image]

If you have a lower edition of Windows 7, you can configure this in the registry. Open `regedit.exe`, and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`. Find the dword value `ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin`, or if it doesn't exist, create it. Set it equal to `00000001`.

Once this is set up, you will be asked for your password when you run any administrative program, such as the MMC or some control panel applets.

[image]